# react setstate immediately and rerender

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react , just trying to upload file via input tag, since the file could be large so while uploading I want to show feedback that the system is currently working with some text in UI like 'Uploading.....'. To do that I am doing:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';
import createReactClass from 'create-react-class';
import i18n from 'ar-i18n';
import _ from 'lodash';

const DragAndDropContainer = createReactClass({
propTypes: {
    onDropFile: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
},

getInitialState () {
    return { currentFile: null, uploadState: false };
},

render () {
    const dragAndDropId = _.uniqueId('drag-and-drop-file-');
    return (
        <div className='drag-and-drop-container'>
            {

                this.state.currentFile && (
                    <p className='drag-and-drop-current-file'>
                        <strong>{ this.state.currentFile.name }</strong>
                    </p>
                )

            }
            {

                !this.state.currentFile && this.state.uploadState && (
                    <p className='drag-and-drop-current-file'>
                        <strong>{i18n.gettext('Uploading......')}</strong>
                    </p>
                )

            }

            <div
                className='drag-and-drop-area'
                onDragEnter={e => e.preventDefault()}

                onDrop={this.onDrop}
                onDragOver={e => e.preventDefault()}
            >
                <img src={assetUrl('upload.png')} />
                <input
                    id={dragAndDropId}
                    className='drag-and-drop-file'
                    name='files[]'
                    type='file'
                    onChange={this.onFileSelected}
                />
                <p>
                    <label className='drag-and-drop-label' htmlFor={dragAndDropId}>
                        <strong>{i18n.gettext('Choose a file or drop it here')}</strong>
                    </label>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
},

onDrop (e) {
    this.onFileSelected(e);
    e.preventDefault();
},

onFileSelected (e) {
    this.setState({ uploadState: true }, function () {console.log('updated uplodastate---', this.state.uploadState)});
    const file = e.dataTransfer ? e.dataTransfer.files[0] : e.currentTarget.files[0];
    this.setState({ currentFile: file });
    this.props.onDropFile(file);
    // prevents control from "caching" files with same name in consecutive uploads
    e.currentTarget.value = '';
},


});

export default DragAndDropContainer;
```

Due to asynchronous call to `setState`,  condition `!this.state.currentFile && this.state.uploadState` is never true.

how do i set `this.state.uploadState` before `const file = e.dataTransfer ? e.dataTransfer.files[0] : e.currentTarget.files[0]`; to allow it to call render.

Comment: Could you include your entire component instead?

Comment: @Tholle updated

Comment: Can you post code for `onDropFile`

Comment: You never seem to upload your file. You are setting `uploadState` to `true` and immediately set `currentFile` to your file. Don't you want to have `uploadState` set to `true` while you are actually uploading the file to the server?

Comment: i want uploadState set to true and currentFile to null when file is selected and once data is completely transferred in "const file = e.dataTransfer ? e.dataTransfer.files[0] : e.currentTarget.files[0];", it should set currentFile to data collected.

Answer (score 0):

one can put `currentFile` state update in callback to meet condition.

```
this.setState({
    uploadState: true
}, ()=> {
    console.log('updated uplodastate---', this.state.uploadState);

    const file = e.dataTransfer ? e.dataTransfer.files[0] : e.currentTarget.files[0];
    this.setState({
        currentFile: file
    });

});
```

Comment: @dikash glad to help u. Please accept and upvote it if ts working

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `const file = e.dataTransfer ? e.dataTransfer.files[0] : e.currentTarget.files[0]` after the setState and once the state is updated, it will automatically rerender the component.

That is called callback function.

```
onFileSelected (e) {
    this.setState({ uploadState: true }, function () {
      const file = e.dataTransfer ? e.dataTransfer.files[0] : e.currentTarget.files[0];
      this.setState({ currentFile: file });
    });
    this.props.onDropFile(file);
    e.currentTarget.value = '';
}
```